# SimpleXLSXGen: generated excel file is showing to be corrupted

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an excel file in `PHP` using the [SimpleXLSXGen](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen) library. This is my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

    require __DIR__.'/vendor/shuchkin/simplexlsxgen/src/SimpleXLSXGen.php';
    use \Shuchkin\SimpleXLSXGen as SimpleXLSXGen;

    $arr = array();

    /*some logic here to populate my array*/

    $xlsx = new SimpleXLSXGen;
    $xlsx::fromArray($arr)
        ->setDefaultFont('Courier New')
        ->setDefaultFontSize(12)
        ->saveAs("..files/file.xlsx");
?>
```

This code used to work before, but now when I execute it, I keep getting a corrupted excel file generated. Everytime I open the file, it keeps showing:

> Excel cannot open the file 'file.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

I have also debugged the `$arr` that I am pushing into my excel file, and it has the correct values. So why is the generated excel file showing to be corrupted?

Comment: Did you check what that file contains in a text editor?

Comment: It shows some gibberish when I open it with the `notepad`: `PK
    -VÚV½èé   R  
   _rels/.rels­’ÁNÃ0@ï|EäûšnH¡e» ¤Ý`·ÚÄQb û{"LlÚcûùÙòz;‡I}P.ž£Yµ-,›EËÎÇÞÀëþiqªF‡G2p ÛÍÍú…&”ZVŸŠªœX....`